# Convert polyline to rectangle

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, geometry

So problem is:

I have a geocoordinates of polylines, example:

```
`var lines = [
{"type":"polyline","latLngs":[{"lat":55.8662574578028,"lng":37.90008544921874},
{"lat":55.94227871136694,"lng":38.32134246826172}],"color":"#a24ac3"},
{"type":"polyline","latLngs":
[{"lat":55.9643834839687,"lng":38.111915588378906},
{"lat":55.857394661151226,"lng":38.14659118652344}],
"color":"#a24ac3"}]`
```

So i need to build a rectangle around every polyline with width of rectangle what will be with of polilyne, and height will be ~100 meters. Polyline must penetrate at the center inside of this rectangle and not extend beyond the boundaries.

It will be calculated on nodejs. I have no idea how to do that with geo

Comment: Need a little clarity... Should the rectangles be aligned to the lat-long axes - or aligned with the line itself so that the 100meters is effectively thickening the line?

Comment: the result rectangle must be around of line